# Spring multiple autowire candidates

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I would like to solve the following problem. Working on a spring project where I have a spring bean configuration class.

```
package package.bean_config_java;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("package.bean_config_java")
public class Beans {

  @Bean
  public Customer customerHashmark() {
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setFormatter(hashmarkNameFormatter());

    return c;
  }

  @Bean
  public Customer customerUnderscore() {
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setFormatter(underscoreNameFormatter());

    return c;
  }

  @Bean
  public Formatter hashmarkNameFormatter() {
    return new HashmarkNameFormatter();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public Formatter underscoreNameFormatter() {
    return new UnderscoreNameFormatter();
  }
}
```

After I ask for any of the customers from the container it returns with a customer with underscoreNameFormatter.

I tried to debug this, and found that spring calls customer.setFormatter only once during app start and the origin is my configuration class, so that looks ok, but in the end, when i get back my bean from the ctx.getBean method the formater is underscoreNameFormatter in all cases.

So is it even possible to override the injected value?

**Note:** With xml config it's possible to do this

```
<bean class="package.Customer">
  <property name="formatter">
    <bean class="package.HashmarkNameFormatter" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the setter `c.setFormatter(hashmarkNameFormatter());` is called in a @Configuration class this call will set the Formatter bean from the application context which in your case is not the object returned by the hashmarkNameFormatter method but the UnderscoreNameFormatter.

I think if you want to set the UnderscoreNameFormatter for customerUnderscore you could inject it as a parameter to the customerHashmark bean creation method by specifying the typed Formatter:

E.g.

```
@Bean
public Customer customerHashmark(HashmarkNameFormatter hashmarkNameFormatter) {
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setFormatter(hashmarkNameFormatter);

    return c;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would be the reason. When I stop with debug on the line `return c;` and inspect the object the `hashmarkNameFormatter` got set already. Some mechanism of spring replace it to `underscoreNameFormatter` somewhere later, but not via `setFormatter` method since there is no further call on that.

I tried your solution anyway but didn't worked. The same stuff happened, the customer objects formatter field is referencing to an `UnderscoreNameFormatter` object.

Answer (score 0):

Name all your bean and inject them with @Qualifier.

```
package package.bean_config_java;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("package.bean_config_java")
public class Beans {

  @Bean(name="hashmarkNameCustomer")
  public Customer customerHashmark() {
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setFormatter(hashmarkNameFormatter());

    return c;
  }

  @Bean(name="underscoreNameCustomer")
  public Customer customerUnderscore() {
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setFormatter(underscoreNameFormatter());

    return c;
  }

  @Bean
  public Formatter hashmarkNameFormatter() {
    return new HashmarkNameFormatter();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public Formatter underscoreNameFormatter() {
    return new UnderscoreNameFormatter();
  }
}
```

When you need a Customer with HashmarkNameFormatter you just have to do :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("hashmarkNameCustomer")
Customer customer1;
```

For Customer with UnderscoreNameFormatter :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("underscoreNameCustomer")
Customer customer2;
```